# PHP cURL: circumventing '@' denoting a file POST

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to make a cURL post, and one of the parameters includes a string prefixed with the '@' symbol. Typically for a cURL post, the '@' means I'm trying post a file, but in this case, I just want to pass the string prefixed with '@'. Is there a way, or what is the best way to get around this?

Here's my params array:

```
$params = array(
        'UserID'       => $this->username,
        'Password'     => $this->password,
        'Type'         => $type,
        'Symbol'       => $symbol, // this will look something like @CH14
        'Market'       => '',
        'Vendor'       => '',
        'Format'       => 'JSN'
);
```

And here's how my cURL post is taking place (the url is irrelevant to the actual problem.):

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

// Return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

if($response === FALSE)
{
    $error = curl_error($ch);
    $error_code = curl_errno($ch);
    throw new Exception("CURL ERROR: #$error_code\n$error\n");
}

curl_close($ch);

return $response;
```

This works for everything I need it to do except when I need to pass it a symbol with an '@' in front. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [`curl_setopt()` manual entry](https://www.php.net/curl_setopt):

> **CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS**
>
> The full data to post in a HTTP "POST" operation. To post a file, prepend a filename with @ and use the full path. The filetype can be explicitly specified by following the filename with the type in the format ';type=mimetype'. This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with the field name as key and field data as value. If value is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data. **As of PHP 5.2.0, value must be an array if files are passed to this option with the @ prefix.** As of PHP 5.5.0, the @ prefix is deprecated and files can be sent using CURLFile.

Hence, we can simply convert it to a string using [`http_build_query()`](http://www.php.net/http_build_query):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
```

Comment: I gave this a shot, and upon running my script from the command line, I received the error:

Exception: CURL ERROR: #26
failed creating formpost data

Which happens to be the same error I get without including the http_build_query(). I'm on php version 5.2.4 for this particular project. Is there any other information I can provide you that might help?

Comment: @user3375552 What does `var_dump(http_build_query($params))` output? (post the content in your original question)

Comment: Ah, I apologize. I was running an older version of the same script. The http_build_query() works beautifully. It's using the correct string and outputting the correct results. Thank you very much.

Comment: @RedJesper No worries - I had a user yesterday having the same problem (still running old script), but the only difference is that he didn't figure out that he wasn't uploading the new script until after 30 minutes. Quite a headache! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/http_build_query) to build the query string.

From the documentation for the function:

> Generates a **URL-encoded** query string from the associative (or indexed) array provided.

As stated above, it will correctly encode all the special characters as required. It can be used as below:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
```

[**Online demo**](https://eval.in/108537)